# compile vb6 snap-in ocx from command line

Tags: command-line, vb6, snap-in

Is there any specific way to compile vb6 snap-in from command line?
I tried using this command:

```
vb6.exe /m project.vbp
```

It throws application error:

> the instruction at 0x027... referenced at 0x000... The memory could
>   not be read.

But it was compiled without any errors in the vb IDE. 
I'm new to VB6 and don't know much about it. Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Properly installed, legal copy of VB6?  Or something like the pirated so-called "Portable Edition?"  Was an an elevation manifest added to VB6.EXE?  If not, are you running it from an elevated command prompt?

Comment: I'm using the licensed copy of the VB6 only. I didn't add any manifest to the exe and running it from command prompt in normal mode.